# How to prove $|e^{i\theta} - 1| \leq |\theta|$?

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

Prove $|e^{i\theta} - 1| \leq |\theta|$, for all real numbers $\theta$.

Answer (score 5):

$|e^{i\theta} -1| =|i\theta\int_0^{1} e^{it\theta}\, dt|\leq |\theta| |\int_0^{1} 1\, dt|=|\theta|$.

Comment: $i\theta e^{i\theta t} =\frac  d {dt} e^{i\theta t}$. What happens when  you integrate this from $0$ to $1$?

Comment: yes sorry haha ijust realised that thankyou

Comment: is there a specific reasoning i could use for the second step, especially for taking out the $i$

Comment: I am just using the fact that $|i|=1$.

Comment: ah yes so why is integral of $e^{itθ}$ $\leq$ integral of 1

Comment: $|e^{i\theta t}|=1$ because $|e^{ic}|=1$ for all real numbers $c$.

Comment: i know that but i dont really understand why the integral of it is less than the integral of 1?

Comment: $|\int f (t)\, dt| \leq \int |f(t)| \, dt$ for any complex valued integrable function $f$.

Answer (score 1):

Draw the unit circle. Then compare the length of a chord to the arc length.

Comment: You should say that it is the chord from $1$ to $e^{i \theta}$...

Answer (score 0):

$|e^{i\theta} - 1| = |\cos\theta + i\sin\theta -1| = |-2\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2} + 2i\cos\frac{\theta}{2}\sin\frac{\theta}{2}| = |2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}||-\sin\frac{\theta}{2} + i\cos\frac{\theta}{2}|$

$|e^{i\theta} - 1| = 2|\sin\frac{\theta}{2}| $

For $\theta$ in radians, $\sin\theta \leq |\theta|$

$\therefore |e^{i\theta} - 1| = 2|\sin\frac{\theta}{2}| \leq 2\cdot|\frac{\theta}{2}| = |\theta|$

$\therefore |e^{i\theta} - 1| \leq |\theta|$

Q.E.D.