# Inequality with complex exponential

Tags: inequality, exponential-function, fourier-transform

Rudin in Real and Complex Analysis uses this in a proof near the beginning of chapter 9:

> $\displaystyle \left \vert{ \frac {e^{-ixu}-1}{u}}\right\vert \le \vert x \vert$ for all real $u \ne 0$

Why is this true?

Edit: I believe $x$ is real

Comment: Is $x$ real or complex?

Comment: If $x$ is real, then you only need to prove that $(\cos(ux)-1)^2+\sin^2(ux)\leq u^2x^2$. With the identity $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$, this reduces to $2-2\cos(ux)\leq (ux)^2$.

Comment: @cmk I believe it's wholly real, because he prefaces the section with "$\mathrm dx$ refers to the ordinary Lebesgue measure"

Comment: $|e^{-ixu}-1|=|e^{-ixu}-e^{i0}|$ is the length of the straight line between the two points of the unit circle $1$ and $e^{-ixu}$, while $|xu|=|xu-0|$ is the length of the arc between them, possibly plus turning around the circle a few times.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2988169/42969.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\left\vert\frac{e^{-ixu}-1}{u}\right\vert^2=\frac{2-2\cos(xu)}{u^2}=\frac{4\sin^2(\frac{xu}{2})}{u^2}\leq\frac{4(\frac{xu}{2})^2}{u^2}=x^2$$