Complex inequality $|e^z-1|\leq |e^x-1|+e^x|z|$.
How to prove that for complex number $z=x+iy$, the following inequality is true: $|e^z-1|\leq |e^x-1|+e^x|z|$.
I tried the Taylor series and triangle inequality but it wasn't enough.

How did you end up with this inequality ?

It was on last year final exam.

This should help: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2988169/42969

By the triangle inequality, one has
$$|e^{x}e^{iy}-1|=|e^{iy}(e^{x}-e^{-iy})|=|e^{iy}||e^{x}-e^{-iy}|=|e^{x}-e^{-iy}|$$
$$=|e^{x}-e^{x}e^{-iy}+e^{x}e^{-iy}-e^{-iy}|\leq
|e^{x}-e^{x}e^{-iy}|+|e^{x}e^{-iy}-e^{-iy}|$$
$$=e^{x}|1-e^{-iy}|+|e^{-iy}||e^{x}-1|\leq|e^{x}-1|+|y|e^{x},$$
using the fact that  $|1-e^{i y}|\leq |y|$ (see the answer here How to prove $|e^{i\theta} - 1| \leq |\theta|$?).

why do you think the mean value theorem works for complex non real valued functions like $t \to e^{it}$; for example if $y=1$ this would mean $\frac{e^xe^{i }-e^x}{1}=i e^xe^{i c}$ or simplifying stuff we get $e^i-1=ie^{ic}$ but taking absolute values we get a contradiction since LHS has absolute value $2 \sin 1/2 \ne 1$; the solution above is incorrrect

A very useful comment. Answer corrected.
